# Ошибка при декодировании BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

Кодирую BitmapImage (в формате gif) в массив байт, далее передаю этот массив байт по сети, массивы байтов при отправке и пришествию совпадают, далее пытаюсь декодировать и вылетает ошибка:  System.NotSupportedException: "Не удалось обнаружить компонент обработки изображений, который подходит для завершения данной операции."

```
   class EncoderImage
    {
        public static byte[] Encode(BitmapImage image, FormatImagescs format)
        {
            byte[] data;
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

            switch (format)
            {
                case FormatImagescs.JPG:
                    encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
                case FormatImagescs.BMP:
                    encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                    break;
            }

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(ms);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return data;
        }

        public static BitmapSource Decode(byte[] data, int dataLengt)
        {
            var result = GetResult(data, dataLengt);
            //using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
            //{
            //    var image = new BitmapImage();
            //    image.BeginInit();
            //    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // here
            //    image.StreamSource = ms;
            //    image.EndInit();

            //    return image;
            //}
            BitmapSource image; ;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(result))
            {
                //var dec = BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                GifBitmapDecoder decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

                image = decoder.Frames[0];
            }

            return image;
        }

        public static byte[] GetResult(byte[] data, int dataLengt)
        {
            byte[] dataR = new byte[dataLengt];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataLengt; i++)
            {
                dataR[i] = data[i];
            }
            return dataR;
        }
```

Comment: А как вы передаёте по сети? Совпадает ли длина?

Comment: @VladD Передаю через сокет, протокол использую `TCP`, тип сокета `stream`. Длина совпадает

Comment: Даже интересно стало, а используются ли в таких случаях какие нибудь кодеки? Или всё это преобразование в потоке реализовано самим Framework-ом? (вопрос, по большей части, к знающим людям)

Comment: А вы на реальных gif - файлах, забрасывая массив с прочитаным с диска - тестировали? Какой версии gif? Содержит ли gif комментарий, анимацию, мапинг, копирайт, прозрачность? Прямой файл или последовательного приближения? Т.е. сначала найдите gif-ку до 1кбайт и протестируйте на ней.

Comment: @Идентикон: Окей. А проверьте, совпадают ли данные _побайтно_.

Comment: @VladD, Оказалось данные побайтно не совпадали, так как буфер не очищал.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Я с гиф картинками работал, и вообще разве есть разница какие копирайты, прозрачность, разве это уже не дело кодировщика? Я стандартными методами превратил ее в массив байт, значит аналогично из этого массива могу получить обратное.

Comment: @Идентикон: То есть проблема решена?

Comment: @VladD , да проблема решена